# Hide image when macro successfully done

Tags: vba, excel

I have an image on which I have bound macro "Zadat2". I would like to hide the image after the macro is successfully done but if I change the value in cell C3 that image is made visible again.

`done.visible = False` does not function.

My code:

```
Sub zadat2()

    Dim reg, check1 As String
    Dim i, j, done As Integer
    reg = Cells(2, 3).Value
    check1 = Range("C4").Value

    If check1 = "PRAVDA" Then

        i = 2
        j = 1
        done = 0
        Do While Sheets("data").Cells(i, j) <> ""
            If Sheets("data").Cells(i, j) = reg Then
                vytisteno = ZkontrolovatAVytiskoutSoubor()
                cekej = Wait()
                done = Sheets("data").Cells(i, j + 3)
                Sheets("data").Cells(i, j + 3) = done
                done.Visible = False
                Exit Do
            End If
            i = i + 1

        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox ("Opravit, špatný štítek!!!")
    End If

    Cells(3, 3) = ""

    Cells(3, 3).Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Cells(1, 1).Row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your image is named after "ZadatShape"

- place the following statement in your `Sub zadat2()` right after the statement that certifies the *"macro successfully done"* :

  ```
  ActiveSheet.Shapes("ZadatShape").Visible = False '<--| change "ZadatShape" to your actual shape name
  ```
- place the following code in the code pane of the worksheet where the shape is:

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      If Target.Address = "$C$3" Then ActiveSheet.Shapes("ZadatShape").Visible = True '<--| change "ZadatShape" to your actual shape name
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: @FiínekCahů, did you try this?

Comment: I creat new module for Worksheet_Change but I dont known where i call this module. Where i call this module? After I click on img, procedure sucussfully done macro img will be hide. And how can I call worksheet_change ? is it call automaticly? How can I visible img again when I change value in cell C3 ?

Comment: in the VBA IDE activate the Project Window (CTRL+R to make it pop out) , explode the "Microsoft Excel Objects" node and double click the item corresponding to the relevant worksheet to open up its code pane where you'll paste the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` code

Comment: I know :) i try it: D sorry :)

Comment: Did you get through it?

Comment: Super you are best !!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to work with object Shape if you want to hide Image. I`m not sure if there is a function which gives you Shape from a Cell, but there is a function which gives you top-left cell from a shape. You will have to slightly change your approach, but i think some of this functions may be usefull.

```
Sheets("data").Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = True

Sheets("data").Shapes("Picture 1").TopLeftCell.Row 
Sheets("data").Shapes("Picture 1").TopLeftCell.Column

For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    With s
    .Visible = False
    End With
Next s
```

Comment: thank you this part works perfect Sheets("data").Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = True

Comment: Probably I need a automatic macro which will watch changing value in cell C3 and I must call this macro if the C3 change. I dont known how.

Comment: Look at next answer, put macro Worsheet_Change to your macros, it should be automatically called when work sheet changes. Once I also wanted to use it, but it is called after every change to worksheet so it can slow your excel significantly - that was my case. I had to change my approach